# Nonhomogeneous equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $a$,$b$ and $c$ are positive constants and $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are solutions of 
$$
ay^{\prime \prime}+by^{\prime}+cy=g(t)
$$
show that $Y_1(t)-Y_2(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. Is this result valid if $b=0$?

Comment: Suggestion:  check out  [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W(t)=Y_1(t)-Y_2(t)$. Then $W$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $ay''+by'+cy=0$.

The roots of the characteristic equation are $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. Call these roots $r_1$ and $r_2$. Then $W(t)$ is of the form $Ae^{r_1 t}+Be^{r_2t}$ if $r_1\ne r_2$, and $Ae^{r_1 t}+Bte^{r_1 t}$ if $r_1=r_2$.

Now there are two cases to consider. If $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is real, then it is less than $b$, so $r_1$ and $r_2$ are negative, and therefore $e^{r_i t}\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.  (In the case $r_1=r_2$, $te^{r_1 t}$ also has limit $0$.)

If $b^2-4ac$ is negative, then the norm of $e^{r_i t}$ is $e^{-b/2a}$, and this $\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.

For the case $b=0$, and $a$ and $c$ positive, the $r_i$ are pure imaginary, so the $e^{r_i t}$ do not approach $0$.